# To use sms sending api on click of button

Tags: php, ajax, api, sms

I have a php form which makes an ajax call on click of sumbit button to save data in database. I want to call sms api to send these details on click of the same submit button. How do I do that?

I am using it from http://sms.hspsms.com/.

Here is the script which takes data annd save it to database:

```
<script>
     $(function () {
         $('#user-form').on('submit', function(e) {

                $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                    url: './user-details.php',
                    data: $('#user-form').serialize(),
                    success: function () {
                        alert('SUCCESS');
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });     
    </script>
```

Where do I use sms api like:

http://sms.hspsms.com:/sendSMS?username=swati&message=XXXXXXXXXX&sendername=XYZ&smstype=TRANS&numbers=&apikey=XXXXXX

to send the details entered in the form.

Edit: I found the solution and it is posted as an answer.

Comment: please provide some of your tested code which is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using this:

```
 $url = "http://sms.hspsms.com:/sendSMS";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username=xxx&password=xxx&to=XXXXX&message=' . $phone . '&sendername=xxx&smstype=TRANS&numbers=xxxx&apikey=xxx');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        echo $result;
```

inside user-details.php

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand, but if you want to send a SMS (Text Message) then here is how. You don't need any API to send a SMS! Put this code with the other code where you insert it into the database.

```
mail($number.'@'.$provider, '', $message, $headers);
```

**here is a list of common providers.**

Verizon Wireless - vtext.com

Virgin Mobile - vmobl.com

Alltel - sms.alltelwireless.com

ATT - txt.att.net

Boost Mobile - sms.myboostmobile.com

Republic Wireless - text.republicwireless.com

Sprint - messaging.sprintpcs.com

T-Mobile - tmomail.net

U.S. Cellular - email.uscc.net

Adam Khoury covers it [here](https://www.developphp.com/video/PHP/Send-SMS-Text-Messages-to-Mobile-Phone-PHP-Tutorial) at DevelopPHP.com.